# Starting Ubuntu 18.04 with two monitors results in black screen after login page

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, login, multiple-monitors

As the title says Starting ubuntu on my dual boot pc when both monitors are connected to my pc will load till the login part and then both screens turn black and monitors go off. If I start with only one monitor connected and plug in the second monitor once im logged in then both screens work fine. How can I fix this as its quite annoying to unplug and plugin one screen each time I start my pc

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but you could try: - Start with one monitor.
- Find the "Display" settings.
- Set this monitor as the default monitor.
- Restart.

Comment: Alternatively, if you manage to open a terminal while the monitors are off (Ctrl+Alt+T I guess), you could try turning the monitors on via the command line using xrandr. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/155004/switch-monitors-from-the-command-line).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Once I'm in the display settings and try to apply some changes same thing happens. Monitors turn off and I get the same message on both monitors that there is no singal and they are turning off super annoying.